Loading data from Google Reviews
I need to ingest Google Reviews for a specific locations on a daily basis. is it even possible? I am trying to deal with Google API for a couple of days and still didn't succeed. it looks like there is no option to use secret key or something, and always need to authenticate a real user using OAuth. also, what I can see - there is no any tool which provides connector to Google Reviews as a source.
did anyone has any successful experience? the use case looks pretty common - I need to have customer reviews in my DWH. but I cannot find any standard solution in the web.
many thanks for any help
